# List of dicts to/from dict of lists, but with all possible permutations

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-itertools

Coming from question number 5558418, suppose I have a dictionary where values are lists:

```
DL = {'a': [0, 1], 'b': [2, 3]}
```

And I want to convert it to a list of dictionaries, but with *all possible permutations*. That is, instead of

```
LD = [{'a': 0, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3}]
```

I now want:

```
LD = [{'a': 0, 'b': 2}, {'a': 0, 'b': 3}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3}]
```

How can I do that? I think itertools' product() may be handy but I can't quite figure it out.

Bonus: In my actual problem, some values are not lists. How can I do the same as above, but preserving all values that are not lists? e.g.:

```
D = {'a': [0, 1], 'b': [2, 3], 'c':7, 'd':9}
```

Becomes:

```
L = [{'a': 0, 'b': 2, 'c':7, 'd':9}, {'a': 0, 'b': 3, 'c':7, 'd':9}}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':7, 'd':9}}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c':7, 'd':9}}]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure every value is a list and then use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

# DL = {'a': [0, 1], 'b': [2, 3]}
D = {'a': [0, 1], 'b': [2, 3], 'c': 7, 'd': 9}

res = [dict(zip(D, p)) for p in product(*[v if isinstance(v, list) else [v] for v in D.values()])]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'a': 0, 'b': 2, 'c': 7, 'd': 9}, {'a': 0, 'b': 3, 'c': 7, 'd': 9}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 7, 'd': 9}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 7, 'd': 9}]
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much for the quick answer :) It worked here for me.